# How can I check which filesystems have greater than 85% usage?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

How can I check which file systems have greater than 85% usage?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
jumpso           200M  3.8M   197M  2% /tmp
none             32G  444K    32G   1% /dev
/dev/md2         24G   13G    11G  56% /var/mnt/local
/dev/md4         16G  3.2G    12G  22% /var/mnt/local
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please be more specific about what exactly you want to archive.

Comment: I meant value more than 85% of something

Comment: look at your provided output and you can see ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want to list all file systems that are more than 85% full.

For this, we need to inspect and filter the output of `df`:

- virtual file systems like `tmpfs` are not interesting, as they are located in memory and not on any disk, and also barely contain anything
- we must filter the output by comparing the numerical value of the output's 5th (`Use%`) column to our threshold of 85%

```
df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs | awk '$5+0 > 85'
```

If you want to include the column titles int he output as well, try

```
df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs | awk '$5+0 > 85 || NR == 1'
```